# Options after exposure to ABS fumes

Tags: cancer, prevention, inhalation, toxic-fumes

Let's assume someone has an increased risk for leukemia, lymphoma, lung cancer, and maybe even brain cancer because of fumes from ABS material that they have inhaled.

What can they do once they are aware of their risk?

So a few questions:

1. What lifestyle changes can they make, if any, to help lower the risk of those cancers?
2. What tests can they ask their doctor to do on a regular basis to help catch those cancers early? Catching cancer early is key to survival of course.
3. What sort of timeline would they be looking at for developing those cancers? 10 years? 20 years? or even 5 years?
4. Any symptoms they should be on the lookout for?
5. Any other possible cancers that they should consider at risk for?
6. Any other advice?

Comment: Currently, your question is off-topic because it is requesting personal recommendations. I have proposed an edit removing the personal information so that the recommendations can apply to anyone.